# Getting this error when running Synergy: "Connection was refused" (macOS server with a Windows 10 client)

Tags: windows-10, macos, synergy

I hope this is an easy problem: I would like to use Synergy to share my OSX keyboard and mouse with my Windows 10 "Nearly Headless NUC" (I know some of you will get the pun!).  But the Windows 10 system reports

```
NOTE: connecting to 'MacBookHome-10.local': fe80::...
WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection was refused
```

Here's the setup:

#### Server

- MacBookPro running macOS Catalina (10.15.4)
- Synergy 1 Basic v 1.11.1 stable
- Configured as Server, IP Address 192.168.1.10
- In "Server Configuration Window", NUC-10 is configured above MacBookHome-10.local

#### Client

- Intel NUC running Windows-10 Pro v 1903, OS build 18362.836
- Synergy 1 Basic v 1.11.1-stable-55ec3105
- Configured as Client, Client Name: NUC-10, Server: MacBookHome-10.local

#### What I observe

After rebooting both machines, the server (on the Mac) seems to have started normally, but it doesn't report any activity from the client:

```
[2020-05-15T18:24:41] INFO: starting server
[2020-05-15T18:24:41] INFO: config file: /private/var/folders/7x/bsz1mn9d5ps8pzs886s71d9m0000gq/T/Synergy.RTGuIV
[2020-05-15T18:24:41] INFO: log level: INFO
[2020-05-15T18:24:41] INFO: drag and drop enabled
[2020-05-15T18:24:41] NOTE: started server, waiting for clients
2020-05-15 18:24:41.760 synergys[798:6798] starting cocoa loop
```

The client (on Windows), on the other hand, finds the server, but can't connect:

```
[2020-05-15T18:33:52] INFO: connecting to service...
[2020-05-15T18:33:52] INFO: connection established
[2020-05-15T18:33:52] INFO: service status: idle
[2020-05-15T18:34:30] INFO: starting client
[2020-05-15T18:34:30] INFO: config file: C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/Synergy.woDYIP
[2020-05-15T18:34:30] INFO: log level: INFO
[2020-05-15T18:34:30] INFO: service command updated
[2020-05-15T18:34:30] INFO: service command updated
[2020-05-15T18:34:31] INFO: starting new process
[2020-05-15T18:34:31] INFO: activeDesktop:Default
[2020-05-15T18:34:31] INFO: starting new process
[2020-05-15T18:34:32] INFO: drag and drop enabled
[2020-05-15T18:34:32] NOTE: started client
[2020-05-15T18:34:33] NOTE: connecting to 'MacBookHome-10.local': fe80::xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxxx
[2020-05-15T18:34:33] INFO: service status: active
[2020-05-15T18:34:36] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection was refused
[2020-05-15T18:34:38] NOTE: connecting to 'MacBookHome-10.local': fe80::xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxxx
[2020-05-15T18:34:40] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection was refused
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Connection was refused` means :

- no processes is listening  on ip adresss / port
- the incoming connection is rejected by a firewall

In your case your client is trying to connect to a local **IpV6** address , but if you told you server to listen on 192.168.1.10 (**IpV4**) , that will not work .

To fix :

- check the firewall on mac

  - **Security & Privacy** => tab **Firewall** => button **Firewall Options** ... check if synergy is present
- tell synergy server to listen on ipv4/ipv6
- tell synergy client to client by specifying a IP V4

ps: Synergy has been forked by some people => https://github.com/debauchee/barrier

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thanks.  What I don't see is a way to get the Synergy client to use IPV4 nor for the server to use IPV6.  Any info on how to do that?

Comment: @fearless_fool try barrier

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Use `ipconfig` to find your local IP.

---

I had the same problem when I reinstalled Windows. Almost all of times synergy will simply work, but sometimes after Windows re-installation, synergy client unable to connect to server. This probably happened after installing VirtualBox .

I am using synergy version 1.8.8-stable (the last free build).

My problem was synergy server doesn't correctly identifies local IP of the host. Typed the server's IPv4 address into client didn't work, too, because the server gives me wrong information.

Synergy server gives me the following:

> 172.19.16.1,**192.168.56.1**,169.254.188.57 (and so on)

However, issued `ipconfig` on command line, gives me a result

```
...

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::dd5c:b653:a9e4:ef3b%12
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . .
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

...

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::718c:e950:3cf4:d06b%30
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.231
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

From above output, it seems that synergy was using VirtualBox's IPv4 address instead of my local IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving @EchoMike444 the check, since he properly identified the problem.

However, if you are using Synergy (rather than [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier)), you can type the IPv4 address of the Server into the `Server:` field of the client.

That will work, at least until the next time you reboot your router and the addresses change.  Of course, you could also assign a static IP address to your server.